# Flatten inner list without changing outer list in python

Tags: python, list, nested, flatten

So, just typing in python flatten list into stack-overflow/google brings back a huge number of duplicate results. I have tried all of them, and none apply in this specific instance.

I am getting back a database result set from pyodbc which gives me a data structure that I can coerce to a list of lists. The first element (first column) in each row returned is in the form `"a.b.c"`. I would like it to be `"a", "b", "c"`. My first instinct was to split on period, which I did.

Before:

```python
[["a.b.c", "d", 1], ["e.f.g", "h", 2], ... ] # rows left out for brevity
```

After:

```python
# unfortunately, split returns a list, which then gets nested
[[["a", "b", "c"], "d", 1], [["e", "f", "g"], "h", 2], ... ]
```

However, what I'd like to see is:

```python
[["a", "b", "c", "d", 1], ["e", "f", "g", "h", 2], ... ]
```

I tried the previous solutions on stack overflow for flattening a list, but while everyone mentions nested lists, no one says how to flatten *only* the nested lists.

I have tried:

```python
from itertools import chain
for row in rows:
    row = list(chain(row)) # python won't allow modifications in a loop
```

and

```python
rows = [list(chain(row)) for row in rows]
```

I imagine there must be a way, perhaps with yield, to do something like:

```python
for row in rows:
    row = row[0].append(row[1:]) # but this doesn't work either
```

I don't know how to modify the inner lists in a list of lists. If there is a better way than what I've tried so far, I'd love to hear it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *python won't allow modifications in a loop* - That's not what's preventing you from getting what you desire in that situation... by doing that you are just binding the name `row` to a new value, it's *allowed* but achieves nothing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> s = [["a.b.c", "d", 1], ["e.f.g", "h", 2]]
>>> [k[0].split('.') + k[1:] for k in s]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 2]]
```

This takes the list that `split` returns after acting on the first element and adds it to a list consisting of the rest of them.

Comment: +1, no reason to make it nested, then flatten it out, easier just to do it in one fell swoop. Note that in 3.x, one can do `[k.split('.') + rest for k, *rest in s]` for easier reading.

Comment: I like these answers. I'm currently on python 2.7. Is it safe to move up to 3.3 and use an earlier version of pyodbc? The database is vertica. Also, is there a way to fix the nesting, for curiosity's sake?

Comment: You can "repair" the nesting in exactly the same way: `[sublist[0] + sublist[1:] for sublist in nested]` (2.7) or `[head + rest for head, *rest in nested]` (3.x).

Comment: @DSM if you post that as a full answer, I'd definitely give it a +1

Comment: @Caleb I'm just gonna guess it would be better to stay on 2.7 for compaitibility